# I tried alcohol while I was reading prayer, what should I do?

Tags: salat, dua, salat-al-qasr

I recently started reading namaz, I’m 18 and I tried alcohol for the first time, but not a little and I’m very ashamed and the advice torments me on how to read namaz now, have I sinned greatly?

Answer (score 0):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته

ask  اللهﷻ to forgive you and stay more away from forbidden things.
Allahﷻ bless you